# Removing event listeners before leaving a page

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, event-listener, onbeforeunload, onunload

I've developed a javascript drag and drop that mostly uses the standard 'allowdrop', 'drag' and 'drop' events.

I wanted to customise the 'ghosted' dragged object, so I've added a display:none div that get populated with the innerHTML of the draggable element and made visible (display:block;) when the user starts dragging.

The draggable div is absolutely positioned and matches the mouse movements. For this I needed to add 3 event listeners to document.body. They are as follows:

```
document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function (ev) {
    console.log("dragover event triggered");
    ev = ev || window.event;
    ev.preventDefault();
    dragX = ev.pageX;
    dragY = ev.pageY;
    document.getElementById("dragged-container").style.left = (dragX - dragOffsetX) + "px";
    document.getElementById("dragged-container").style.top = (dragY - dragOffsetY - 10) + "px";    
    if (mostRecentHoveredDropTargetId!="") {
        if (dragX<mostRecentHoveredDropTargetRect.left || dragX>mostRecentHoveredDropTargetRect.right || dragY<mostRecentHoveredDropTargetRect.top || dragY>mostRecentHoveredDropTargetRect.bottom) {
            document.getElementById(mostRecentHoveredDropTargetId).classList.remove("drop-target-hover");
            mostRecentHoveredDropTargetId = "";
        }
    }
});

document.body.addEventListener('drop', function (ev) {
    console.log("drop event triggered");
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // data set to the id of the draggable element
    if (document.getElementById(data)!=null) {
        document.getElementById(data).classList.remove("dragged");
        document.getElementById("dragged-container").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("dragged-container").style.display = "none";
        var draggablesClasses = document.getElementById(data).className;
        if ((draggablesClasses.indexOf('draggable')==-1 || draggablesClasses=="") && document.getElementById(data).getAttribute('draggable')=="true") {
            if (draggablesClasses=="") {
                document.getElementById(data).className += "draggable";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(data).className += " draggable";
            }
        }
    }
});

// resets dragged-container and origin .draggable, when mouse released outside browser window
document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (ev) {
    if (jqueryReady==true) {
        $(".dragged").addClass("draggable");
        $(".dragged").removeClass("dragged");
    }
    document.getElementById("dragged-container").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("dragged-container").style.display = "none";
});
```

**This is all working fine. The drag and drop performs exactly as I expect.**

The problem is when I go to another page, obviously those body event listeners are still running.

I've seen a number of answers here and have tried everything I've seen. For starters this:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    console.log("about to clear event listeners prior to leaving page");
    document.body.removeEventListener('dragover', null);
    document.body.removeEventListener('drop', null);
    document.body.removeEventListener('mouseleave', null);
    return;
}
```

...but the console.log output doesn't even appear (let alone the 'null's being wrong, I'm pretty sure). I've also tried this, in the jQuery ready function:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        console.log("about to clear event listeners prior to leaving page");
        document.body.removeEventListener('dragover', null);
        document.body.removeEventListener('drop', null);
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseleave', null);
    });
```

..but, once again, the console isn't even receiving that output.

I have also tried both the above with 'onbeforeunload' AND 'onunload'.

What am I doing wrong? - specifically to do with removing these window.body event listeners, I mean (Anything else I can sort out later).

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**removeEventListener requires the handler**

Don't use anonymous functions is the solution.
Like this:

```
var dragHandler = function (ev) {
    console.log("dragover event triggered");
};
document.body.addEventListener('dragover', dragHandler);
```

and after:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    console.log("about to clear event listeners prior to leaving page");
    document.body.removeEventListener('dragover', dragHandler);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I knew the 'null's were probably wrong, but that's not my immediate problem. I've updated my code and the drag and drop still all works but, as before the .onunload function is not even getting called - no console output. It just occurred to me that I could put the add and remove event lines in the 'drag' and 'drop' event handlers for the dragged elements. That seems to have done the trick. But thanks for clearing up the non-anonymous function problem.