# JS - How to remove an active eventListener without reloading the web page

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I have a playGame() function that initiates an eventListener. Each time a new game is started, the playGame() function seems to create an additional eventListener. How can I remove the active eventListener so each time the game is played, so a new one is not added.

I have tried to use the removeEventListener as outlined here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener . 
I've also looked similar issues on stack overflow (like [Removing event listeners before leaving a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918366/removing-event-listeners-before-leaving-a-page) ) but the solution there did not apply.

Here is how the function is laid out. I try to remove the old eventListener prior to loading the rest of the game scripts.

```js
function playGame() {
    console.log('new game');
    // should remove event listener from previous game
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', function() {userInput(activeStringObj, event.key);});

    loadStartOutput();
    wordPicker(activeStringObj);
    addLetterDivs(activeStringObj); 
    addHint(activeStringObj);

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {userInput(activeStringObj, event.key);});
}
```

I am logging the array that records the users key presses and it is obvious that multiple eventListeners are recording the inputs.

```
new game (typed 'a' 's')

game.js:98 ["a"]

game.js:98 (2) ["a", "s"]

new game (typed 'd' 'f')

game.js:98 (3) ["a", "s", "d"]

game.js:98 (4) ["a", "s", "d", "d"]

game.js:98 (5) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f"]

game.js:98 (6) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f"]

new game (typed 'h' 'j')

game.js:98 (7) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h"]

game.js:98 (8) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h", "h"]

game.js:98 (9) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h", "h", "h"]

game.js:98 (10) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h", "h", "h", "j"]

game.js:98 (11) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h", "h", "h", "j", "j"]

game.js:98 (12) ["a", "s", "d", "d", "f", "f", "h", "h", "h", "j", "j", "j"]
```

I am expecting only a single letter to be added to the array each time a key is pressed.

Comment: Could it be possible that instead of the eventListener not being removed, it is being initiated twice?

Comment: That is a good consideration. However, only one seems to be added when the game is started after a page refresh. After that, each time the game is restarted, it seems there is only one extra listener adding to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding and removing event listeners the handler function(including the function signature) should be the same. In your code, you have written identical function definition, twice! This means an identical function is declared twice. Its not the same function. Instead, try this:

```
function takeAction(event) {
    userInput(activeStringObj, event.key)
}

function playGame() {
    console.log('new game');
    // should remove event listener from previous game
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', takeAction);

    loadStartOutput();
    wordPicker(activeStringObj);
    addLetterDivs(activeStringObj); 
    addHint(activeStringObj);

    document.addEventListener('keyup', takeAction);
}
```

This should do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the same function to remove, by pointer, the functions bodies are the same but they are not the same object, it's 2 separate pointers to 2 different function objects with same body.

Or add event listener once, and pass to the handler current game object you have as an argument